# Drag and drop in cucumber with watir-webdriver

Tags: drag-and-drop, cucumber, watir-webdriver

Which command may I use to drag and drop with cucumber-testing?

Comment: You should provide some evidence that you did some work before asking the question. Did you at least google for: "watir drag and drop"?

Comment: yes, of course, otherwise I would not ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [watir-webdriver API docs](http://watir.github.com/watir-webdriver/doc/Watir/Element.html#drag_and_drop_on-instance_method):

```
a = browser.div(:id => "draggable")
b = browser.div(:id => "droppable")

a.drag_and_drop_on b
```